# Workspace in Pycharm community 3.4.1

Tags: pycharm

Is there a way to see all the variables, values, class, etc information in Pycharm community. I am looking for something like in Matlab workspace feature?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use debuger instead.
Add breakpoint and then click on "Debug"(Shift+F9) instead of "Run". You will see all workspace variables. If you need debug console you have to be sure that in Settings->Console "Always show debug console" is checked.